# What was spammy, rude or abusive about this answer?

Tags: discussion, flagging, spam

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/264368/revisions) was marked as 'spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown'

> What was the first song you ever learned? Was it like mine, the top movie kind? What kind of dream did you have last night? Why can't you answer me?
>
> The Voight-Kampff test referenced in this song by Sandii and Ryuichi Sakamoto
>
> [RACHAEL / SANDII & THE SUNSETZ](https://youtu.be/FZr-b11Ob4c?t=84)

I'll happily admit that I didn't think it was very good, but I'm not seeing any justification for it being marked as spam (the user was brand new and a cursory search suggests that they aren't connected to the video in the link), nor is there any abusive content.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Was it *actually deleted as spam or R/A* (i.e. deleted by Community and locked)? Or, is it merely hidden such that non-moderators have to click through to the revision history (indicating only that there's one or more "helpful" spam or R/A flags on the post, which might have been automatically marked helpful when the post was deleted, without anyone actually evaluating the flag)?

Comment: @Makyen it was deleted from a moderator red flag as far as I can tell. I’ll let the mod who did so answer though as I’ve not really looked at the post in question.

Comment: Looks like spam to me. Even if it wasn't *intended* as spam, it's *effectively* spam.

Comment: @Makyen - How so? OP is quoting song lyrics that he believes are relevant to the question, and has helpfully provided a link to the song in question on YouTube.

Comment: @Valorum I can't see deleted posts, so there's no way for me to know that the answer has any relevance to the question. The text you've included isn't indicated as a quote of lyrics of the song. Did the question ask about finding references in pop culture to the Voight-Kampff test? If not, then it's just someone posting a link to their favorite, potentially related, song, which is promotion/spam.

Comment: @cigien The entire text of the post is reproduced in the question.  That's all there is.  Personally I didn't think it was an actual answer, and am not sorry to have it deleted, but it didn't smell like spam/abuse to me.

Comment: @DavidW - It's possibly an answer. If OP could show that the song was in some way licensed or connected with the film

Comment: Certainly it was an attempt at an answer. I was surprised as well when I saw it had been deleted as spam so quickly

Comment: It couldn't possibly constitute an answer as the song came out 16 years *after* Do Androids Dream... Unless you count it as just a wrong answer. I'm pretty sure that I flagged to delete as not an answer but my review history won't give details.

Comment: @JiminyCricket.is the question limited to just the novel?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage not limited to the novel, but probably to in-universe? Questions asked outside could come from any source and be just as valid then?

Comment: @Skooba - If OP can show that the song is intended to be based on Deckard's test on the (titular) Rachael, then it would certainly be *an answer*, albeit based on what is essentially fan-fic.

Comment: @Valorum OP cannot basically show this and, instead, [becomes rude when questioned](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14060/770). I think it was right to both downvote and delete his answer as random junk.

Answer (score 26):

### It was flagged in error

I flagged it, because I mistook it for trying to advertise the song.

I should have taken a second look.

But by the power of mod magic the spam flag has been removed and the answer undeleted.

---

I've also made some edits to the answer, to make it clearer that it's actually an answer and not just a post about a song.